# Intellij IDEA 2017.2.4 copyright template not saved

Tags: intellij-idea

Each time I create a copyright profile in IntelliJ 2017.2.4 (File/Settings/Editor/Copyright Profiles), I am able only to use that profile with the project that I create it in. The next project that I create is missing any of the previous copyright profiles that I've created and I must recreate another profile.

Has anyone else seen such behavior? Is this a defect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Copyright Profiles` you define in IntelliJ are always defined for the **current project**.

The preferences dialog in which you define the profile states this:

[image]

There are some YourTrack issues open against IntelliJ related to this:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136468
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136467

In the meantime, you *could* share profiles between projects by defining the copyright text in a file and importing that file into each of your projects. You'll find the import option available at `File > Settings > Editor > Copyright > Copyright Profiles`. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

You can inmport any file which contains the copyright content.

More details [in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copyright-profiles.html).

Comment: OK, thanks for the confirmation. Reading the issues you link above, it doesn't seem that the JetBrains folks understand that there is a legitimate use case for global Copyright configurations. That's too bad.

Comment: I confirm that the copyright profile is not saved. It is annoying to import it every time I open the app.